# How to works with indexes in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, indexing

We have html code like:

```
<div class="blocks">
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
    <div class="block"></div>
</div>
```

How do I get:

1) first five elements?

2) number of visible blocks (they can be invisible).

3) number of all elements?

4) number of invisible elements?

5) make visible element(`n`)?

6) make invisible elements from `n` to `n`?

`n` is an index number.

That's all corresponding only to `.block` divs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1) first five elements?

```
$('.block:lt("5")'); // zero-based indexing.
```

2) number of visible blocks (they can be invisible).

```
$('.block:visible').length; // gets all visible '.block' elements.

$('.block:visible:lt("5")'); // the first five elements
$('.block:visible:gt("2")'); // all elements after the third (zero-based indexing)
```

3) number of all elements?

```
$('.block').length;
```

4) number of invisible elements?

```
$('.block').not(':visible');
$('.block:hidden'); // thanks @strager
```

5) make visible element(n)?

```
$('.block').eq(n).show();
```

6) make invisible elements from n to n?

```
$('.block').each(
    function(i){
    var lowBound = 2, highBound = 10;
        if (i > lowBound && i < highBound) {
            $(this).hide();
        }
     });

$('.block').slice(low, high).hide(); // use this approach, it's much better! Thanks, again, @strager
```

---

References:

- [`lt()`](http://api.jquery.com/lt/).
- [`gt()`](http://api.jquery.com/gt/).
- [`not()`](http://api.jquery.com/not/).
- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/).
- [`each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/).
- [`index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/).

Comment: Alternative for 4: `$('.block:hidden')`  Alternative for 6: `$('.block').slice(low, high).hide();`

Comment: I couldn't find the documentation for `lt` and `gt` methods (but I haven't tested your examples).  An alternative is to use `slice`, as my above alternative for 6.

Comment: @strager, thanks! I *knew* there was a shorter version for 4, but for my brain was lying and making me try and use `:invisible` for some reason... =/ your alternatives edited in, and your 6 is excellent! :)

Comment: @Rooney, you're absolutely welcome; I'm glad to have been of help! If my answer was useful to you please feel free to up-vote or accept :)

Answer (score 1):

The JQuery site has good documentation with examples on using Selectors.

- [Selectors Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)

This site is useful giving examples and you can try out the selectors as a learning exercise.

- [Selectors Examples](http://codylindley.com/jqueryselectors/)